# Confirmation message using Spring AOP - AspectJ

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to learn Spring AOP implementation using AspectJ. 
I have 5 classes in different packages.

```
package com.sample.a;
Class A{
    public void save(){
    }
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.sample.b;
Class B {
    public void save(){
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.sample.c;
Class C {
    public void save(){
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.sample.d;
Class D{
    public void save(){
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.sample.e;
Class E{
    public void save(){
    }
}
```

Whenever these  method gets called, I need to print "Hello World", How can I achieve the above scenario using Spring AOP (AspectJ). I have done the following so far -

**1) Enabled Spring AspectJ support in applicationContext.xml**

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

**2) Defined reference of Aspect in applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="sampleAspectJ" class="com.sample.xxxxxxxx" />
```

3) Aspect Class

```
/**
 * aspect class that contains after advice 
 */
package com.sample;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class SpringAopSample{

    @After(value = "execution(* com.sample.*.Save(..))")
    public void test(JoinPoint joinPoint) {


        System.out.println("Hello World");



    }

}
```

is there any better way to achieve the above scenario? what if these 5 classes are in different packages and have different method names? Do I need to write 5 different methods in aspect (annotated with @after advice)

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? What exactly do you want your pointcut to match?

Comment: About your questions - "what if these 5 classes are in different packages and have different method names?" - If they have different names you would still need to have some common pattern so that you can create a regex otherwise the aspect will get applied to all methods in the class which may not be intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get acquainted with AspectJ pointcut syntax. For instance

- your own pointcut `execution(* com.sample.*.Save(..))` from the example will not match any of the sample `save()` methods because

  - you wrote `Save()` with a capital "S", but the methods have lower-case "s" as their first character,
  - your classes would rather match `com.sample.*.*` (sub-package!) than just `com.sample.*`.
- So you can match all `save()` methods in sub-package classes like this: `execution(* com.sample.*.*.save(..))`. The first `*` is the subpackage `a` to `d`, the second `*` is the class name.
- If you want to match sub-packages and even classes hierarchically to any depth you can just use the `..` syntax like this: `execution(* com.sample..save(..))`
- If you want to match only `public void` methods of any name and without parameters in all sub-packages, you can use `execution(public void com.sample..*())`

And so forth. I hope this answers your question even though it is kind of unclear what exactly you want to know.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer indeed has cleared lot of doubts.

Comment: I have a little doubt. Class A, B, C, D and E have to be service layer classes annotated with @Service or @Component?